# Не могу активировать учетную запись в AD. ldap3, python

Tags: python, ldap

Не могу активировать учетку. Пробовал сразу прописывать userAccountControl 512 при создании пользователя и после создания учетки обновить этот атрибут, что там, что там получаю unwillingToPerform.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код выглядит так:

```
new_user = {
        'objectClass': ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user'],
        'sAMAccountName': loginNew,
        'displayName': nameNew,
        'altSecurityIdentities': public_key,
        'userPassword': passwordE,
        'userAccountControl': 512
    }
```

Также пробовал отдельно обновить атрибут userAccountControl через conn.modify
тоже получаю сообщение "unwillingToPerform"

Подходил к админу AD. Говорит, что права у меня полные, проблема в моем коде.
Кто сталкивался? Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Подключаетесь ли Вы с помощью SSL? Приведите полный код Вашего скрипта.

Active Directory отказывает в операции изменения пароля, если используется незащещённое соединение, а без установленного пароля активировать учётную запись не получится

Попробуйте добавить параметр `use_ssl=True` в настройки подключения к серверу

Пример:

```
def ldap_server():
    return Server(LDAP_HOST, get_info=ALL, use_ssl=True)
```

Comment: для того, чтобы задать уточняющие вопросы автору вопроса, служат комментарии.